# $\cos ^2(x)=\frac{1}{2} \cos (2 x)+\frac{1}{2}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I am wondering how this is rewritten?

$$\cos ^2(x)=\frac{1}{2} \cos (2 x)+\frac{1}{2}$$,

I think it has something to do with double-angle/half angle? but I am not sure and I do not see the connections

Comment: You may be familiar  with the version $\cos 2x=2\cos^2 x-1$.

Comment: HINT: Start with $\cos(2x)=\cos(x)\cos(x)-\sin(x)\sin(x)=\cos^2(x)-\sin^2(x)$. Then use the identity $\cos^2(x)+\sin^2(x)=1$ to replace $\sin^2(x)$ in the first expression.

Comment: The hints was very helpful. Now how can I accept the hints as answers? Maybe the question is too simple to have? should I delete it?

Comment: No need to delete the question. I am here to help rather than to collect points :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Taken from Mufasa's comment:

Hint: Start with $\cos2\theta=\cos\theta\cos\theta-\sin\theta\sin\theta=\cos^2\theta-\sin^2\theta$

Then use the Pythagorean identity $\cos^2\theta+\sin^2\theta=1$ to replace $\sin^2x$ in the first expression.

Answer (score 0):

By
$$
    Cos^2(x)-Sin^2(x)=Cos(2x)
$$
and
$$
Cos^2(x)+Sin^2(x)=Cos(0)
$$
We can obtain that
$$
Cos^2(x)=0.5cos(2x)+0.5
$$